# Is there any ncurses archiver interface available?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, archive, tar, ncurses

I am looking for a way to create archives on the commandline with some minimal ASCII interface.

Could be for tar, zip or rar files, but should provide miniml ncurses (or other) "fake" graphical interface. I tried with midnight commander but could not find an entry in the menu to create an archive from selected files.

Also great would be to have an option "archive and test" or even better "arcive and test and delete originals on success".

Comment: It's not ncurses, but have you tried p7zip?

Comment: p7zip (really the `7z` command from the p7zip-full package) has always worked great for me in a terminal. It's just that if you're looking to emulate a GUI in the terminal via ncurses, that's not the way to go. `7z` doesn't require a GUI at all.

Answer (score 1):

We have a winner: https://github.com/matejc/tarman

I've been using Matej's code since the beginning he coded the project, It's handy.